# How to get charts and reports in html5 dynamically?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm working on an android tablet application using phonegap in which i need to get a report chart which diagrammatically explains the status of different things, something like as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I want to generate these kind of charts or reports dynamically which varies as the data changes.Can anyone help me providing some examples using html5, js and css which has some similar functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check out **RGraph: HTML5 & Javascript charts**?

**RGraph** is a charts library written in Javascript that uses HTML5 to draw and supports over twenty different types of charts. Using the new HTML5 canvas tag, RGraph creates these charts inside the web browser using Javascript, meaning quicker pages and less web server load. This leads to smaller page sizes, lower costs and faster websites - everybody wins!

---

If you see a basic code, it goes this way:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        // The data to be shown on the Pie chart
        var data = [564,155,499,611,322];

        // Create the Pie chart. The arguments are the canvas ID and the data to be shown.
        var pie = new RGraph.Pie('myPie', data);

        // Configure the chart to look as you want.
        pie.Set('chart.labels', ['Abc', 'Def', 'Ghi', 'Jkl', 'Mno']);
        pie.Set('chart.linewidth', 5);
        pie.Set('chart.stroke', 'white');

        // Call the .Draw() chart to draw the Pie chart.
        pie.Draw();
    }
</script>
```

See a live example of [Pie charts](http://www.rgraph.net/examples/pie.html)!

---

Yours is a Radar Chart. See one here: [Radar Charts](http://www.rgraph.net/examples/radar.html). Source code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        // The data to be represented on the Radar chart.
        var data = [3, 3, 41, 37, 16];

        // Create the Radar chart. The arguments are the canvas ID and the data to be shown on the chart.
        var radar = new RGraph.Radar('myRadar', data);

        // If you want to show multiple data sets, then you give them like this:
        // var radar = new RGraph.Radar('myRadar', [3,5,6,8], [4,5,2,6]);

        // Configure the Radar chart to look as you wish.
        radar.Set('chart.background.circles', true);
        radar.Set('chart.color', 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');
        radar.Set('chart.circle', 20);
        radar.Set('chart.circle.fill', 'rgba(200,255,200,0.5)');
        radar.Set('chart.labels', ['Safari (3%)', 'Other (3%)', 'MSIE 7 (41%)', 'MSIE 6 (37%)', 'Firefox (16%)']);
        radar.Set('chart.key', ['Market share', 'A made up figure']);

        // Now call the .Draw() method to draw the chart.
        radar.Draw();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response i have got a link http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/#!basic-radar which is what exactly i wanted but not able to implement the given js code to get that view can u help me in this case? thank you

Comment: @androidfresher Okay, what is the issue you are facing when you try to implement this? What have you done so far?

Comment: i added that js file and the flotr2.min.js as they said in docs but not able to understand where to call the function in order to display.The have source code in github can u help me?

Comment: Will try out and let you know, and I will update the answer. :)

Comment: FYI RGraph is now MIT licensed too - which basically means "Do what you like with it". SVG chart types have arrived too, just a Bar, Line and Pie at the moment but more are coming.

Comment: @Richard That's great to hear... `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link.It really has some good examples.

http://www.highcharts.com/

Let me know if you still have any issues

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to map [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) to the graph.  [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1) is a basic example demonstrating what you can do without using any javascript.

[Here](http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/26/30-pure-css-alternatives-to-javascript/) are some static examples produced with css (no javascript), I'm having a hard time finding interactive examples but as demonstrated in one of the previous links it is possible.